# Why is doGet() failing without posting logs?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, urlfetch

I suppose my question is twofold: `doGet()` in the following context will just fail after 0.1~0.2 seconds without posting logs, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot it by myself. Additionally, if I'm having the script execute on my behalf, do I have to push a request with my authorization token to a more "pertinent" area than just the sheet name, such as within the iteration itself? Read further for more details:

I have a source spreadsheet where I am cross-referencing user inputted data to validate the information we have "on file". Most of our clients are over the age of 55, so I am trying to reduce end-user complexity by having the script run on my behalf whenever they need to use it (to bypass the Authorization screen, with the big scary "This application could be unsafe!" message). The way I've read to accomplish this seems to be with `doGet()`, so I set up a low-level HTTP Get request that just pushes a `doGet()` with my OAuth token, returning the sheet name. I also set up a masking function specifically to do this, and linked it to the button originally used for the iteration logic. The `doGet()` looks like this:

```
const doGet = e => {
  Logger.log(`Recieved HTTP request.`);
  const content = ContentService.createTextOutput(iterator(e));
  Logger.log(content);
  return content;
}
```

and the button that uses `UrlFetchApp` looks like:

```
const runMask = () => {
  const active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  const v4 = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/<scriptid>/dev' // ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() posts  404

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${v4}?sheetName='${active}'`, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
  });
```

I have some logs set up within the real `runMask()` that proceed all the way to the end of the program, giving me real URLs and OAuth tokens, so I know it's making it through `runMask()` without an issue. However, the `doGet()` log doesn't post anything, even at the top of the function. I can see that it's executing the trigger in my execution log, but the log itself remains empty.

I've tried:

- using `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` in place of `v4`: posts 404 in the log w/ truncated server response
- replacing `${active}` with the name of the sheet: same issue; logging `${active}` also returns the correct name of the sheet.

Beyond this, I'm not even sure what to do. I have everything scoped correctly (`auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`, `auth/script.external_request`, and `auth/userinfo.email`), and I have no issues about operational security (as both the spreadsheet and script are written by me, the clients have no need to grant access to their entire drive). Before trying to implement `doGet()` and bypass the authorization screen, the iterator itself worked just fine. As such, I have chosen not to include it here, as it's hardly relevant (the function that executes the iteration function never makes it to that point).

I understand this has been quite the deluge of information; I'd be happy to provide more information or context as needed.

Comment: By guessing your situation from your question, I proposed modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: If any of the current answers solve your issue please provide a [mcve].

Comment: After reading the answer posted by [Ruben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72312406/17966100), I set up a `__test__doGet` function, which completes the function's execution when it calls `doGet()` at the end, even when passing it an empty parameter object. The issue seems to be with `runMask`, `UrlFetch`, or some combination of the two.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please add a [mcve] including the appsscript.json file.

Comment: It's posting logs now, but I'm not sure which answer to mark as correct.... it's a little bit of everyone's. I'm just having another issue now. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting ReferenceError: iterator is not defined (line 12, file "ag2")

With this:

```
const doGet = e => {
  Logger.log(`Recieved HTTP request.`);
  const content = ContentService.createTextOutput(iterator(e));
  Logger.log(content);
  return content;
}
```

Issued with url/exec?option=A

It runs with

```
const doGet = e => {
  Logger.log(`Recieved HTTP request.`);
  const content = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
  Logger.log(content);
  return content;
}
```

and returns the appropriate stringified object

Answer (score 0):

Only use the test URL (`/dev`) for testing the web app from a web browser.

Before doGet from a web browser using a versioned deployment (`/exec`) remember to publish a new version.

Assign a Google Cloud Project to your Google Apps Script project. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects.

To make it easier to debug your avoid calling functions from a Google Apps Script method like `createTextOutput`, instead, assign the function result to a variable and use it as the method parameter, i.e. replace

```
const content = ContentService.createTextOutput(iterator(e));
```

by

```
const something = iterator(e);
const content = ContentService.createTextOutput(something);
```

For debugging purposes, create a function to call your doGet function, and check that it hasn't any problem to run, i.e.

```
function __test__doGet(){
  const e = {
    parameter: {}
  }

  doGet(e);
}
```

Related

- [Exception handling in google apps script web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46562705/1595451)

Comment: Even after deploying and updating the link to /exec, using /exec vs. /dev never made a difference in testing; sorry I failed to explain that in my initial post. I am only using dev now as I was under the impression that you could use either one in the script; I have a bit of an aversion to version spamming.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

When I saw your question, I'm worried about `I have everything scoped correctly (auth/spreadsheets.currentonly, auth/script.external_request, and auth/userinfo.email)`.

If you are using only the following scopes at `oauthScopes` of `appsscript.json`,

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

Unfortunately, these scopes cannot be used for access to Web Apps. Although I'm not sure about the method for running your function of `runMask`, I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

#### Solution:

If you want to access Web Apps of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<scriptid>/dev` using the access token retrieved by `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`, please include the following scope.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

After you include the above scope, please reauthorize the scopes, and test it again. When your function of `iterator` has already been declared and the script worked, by running `runMask`, you can see the log of `Logger.log(`Recieved HTTP request.`)` and `Logger.log(content)` at the log.

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you for the information, I didn't know I needed `/auth/drive`. However, this didn't fix my issue; I wasn't explicitly setting scopes in the first place, although I am now with no change. Thanks again!

Comment: @rgr0 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your scopes of your question, I thought that you might set the specific scopes in `appsscript.json`. About `However, this didn't fix my issue; I wasn't explicitly setting scopes in the first place, although I am now with no change.`, I cannot understand your situation. In your current situation, what scopes are you using? I think that if the scopes of Drive API are not included, the script cannot access the Web Apps. How about this? Can you provide the detail of your current situation?